# Blank spaces in HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm new to HTML and I'm wondering if there are efficient ways other than brute force using white-spaces to create the following sample table:

[image]

I've tried making it but the code was not pretty. I would appreciate much of your help and tips.

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) page so that we can readily try things out?

Comment: I think you'll need CSS for this task.

Comment: Smells like using tables for layout... `:-/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td class="lcol"></td><td class="mcol"></td><td class="rcol"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="mrow"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="brow"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.lcol { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
.mcol { width: 400px; }
.rcol { width: 40px; }
.mrow { height: 400px; }
.brow { height: 40px; }
```

Obviously adjust the pixel sizes as required. You can use "%" too if you want to fit to page.

**Edit**: If you want the borders displayed, then in css:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #000; }
td { border: 1px solid #000; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive yet to come upon CSS and I initially thought they were only for fonts / colors etc., but I read more about it after this post and found that its really useful for a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

why not use `&nbsp;`.It is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this   occupies.